# Strict config causes Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to read some environment variables from Window. In my `env.js` I set a variable like this:

```
(function(window) {
  window["env"] = window["env"] || {};

  window["env"]["apiURL"] = "https://localhost:44388";
})(this);
```

And then I want to read it in an environment file like this (`env.dev.ts`):

```
const apiUrl= window['env']['apiURL'];

export const environment = {
  url: {
    apiBaseUrl: `${apiUrl}`,
  },
};
```

That causes a red line under ['env'] in my `environment.dev.ts` file stating `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'`. A workaround is to set `strict: false` in `tsconfig.json`, but I would like to keep `strict: true`. It's also possible to suppress these kinds of warnings, but that seems pretty hacky. Is there another way I could read this `apiURL` variable?

Comment: What about type assertion https://www.javatpoint.com/typescript-type-assertion?

Comment: If you want the compiler to know about `env` and its type, you can tell it so by [merging that information](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) into the `Window` interface, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0Y1OW). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That seems to do the trick @jcalz! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), which lets you "add" things to existing declarations.  Since you expect `window` to have an `env` property of type `{apiURL: string}`, and since `window` is of the global [`Window` interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9dfd5ea221fa6cbfec1c8dbe40aa24e4a70dc742/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L17582-L17701) type, you can just merge that property in via [`global` augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation):

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    env: {
      apiURL: string
    }
  }
}
```

After that, things should work as desired:

```
const apiUrl = window['env']['apiURL']; // okay
// const apiUrl: string

export const environment = {
  url: {
    apiBaseUrl: `${apiUrl}`,
  },
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoe8AlgHYAuIMAZlGAgOonAoDuO+B8IxAbgFxscOUAA6EAqgCUAMvwDOpGCUTsCAX3br1uMCmLz4I8TCwBeeM0YsA2gHIu3GwF1bhyVKcBueLgD0P+Dp6pAaiYsbwZhbETMwAdPaxrtIevv6B+q7GcgpKuHkgAB7CKDDB6cH2hDC6ALZcwWZ4BACuWQJCogBCULIgYRD8AAYAJNiZEKqDADQaM6oeQA)